# Динамические поля MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Было одно из тестовых заданий, звучит так:

"Создать БД хранящую
1 Номер лицевого счета
2 Его название
3 Дату открытия счета
4 ФИО исполнителя* (Сотрудник ответственный за счет. Может меняться в зависимости от даты, 01.03.2015 это Иванов, а 04.03.2015 это петров, а 12.03.2015 это опять Иванов)

Подумав пару минут придумал такую базу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

таблица с лицевыми счетами и таблица с сотрудниками исполнителями, в которой его ФИО, номер ЛС за который он ответственный и Дата его ответственности.

И эвент который меняет значение FIO в ls если вдруг сегодняшняя дата соответствует дате наступления ответственности у другого исполнителя. Событие срабатывает каждый день.

В условии так же было сказано, что реализация может быть любой.
Однако решение не засчитали из-за неверного подхода в принципе. От чего я полагаю есть способ куда более правильный? У кого какие идеи?

Answer (score 2):

Тут напрашивается не ежедневное событие, а триггер на вставку/изменение данных в `exec`.
К примеру: что будет, когда в `exec` внесут запись задним числом? Скажем, 02.04.2016 введут данные о том, что с 01.04.2016 клиента ведет Иванов, а не Петров? Событие отработает только когда отработает, и до этого момента в базе будет указано, что клиента ведёт Петров. Триггер отработает сразу.
Это если нужно именно хранить данные в таблице.
Если такого условия не стоит, а нужно просто знать кто на текущую дату ведет счет - можно сделать представление (View).

Ну и хранение ФИО - нарушение нормальной формы. Создайте справочник сотрудников, храните ключ в обеих таблицах.

Comment: А можно немного подробнее как это во View можно узнать кто ведет счет сегодня при этом не храня данные в таблице? Вьюшка разве не из таблиц данные берет?

Comment: Ну, тут я вижу два варианта. Либо вьюха будет выдавать записи по всем периодам и потом запросом это будем фильтровать, либо вьюха будет использовать NOW() и выдавать данные на текущую дату.

Answer (score 2):

Есть таблица счетов,как у Вас.
таблица сотрудников и табл связей(сотрудник-дата).
добавляете befor insert триггер на вставку в табл ls(примеров в инете много) и делаете выборку по таблице связей,какой из сотрудников сегодня ответственный(тоесть по вставленной дате) и вставляете этот результат в таблицу счета с остальными данными.
ну смысл такой. Это первый вариант.
ну а второй-это просто,через sql join посмотреть,кто из сотрудников ответственный за определенный день
select ls.Id,ls.Date,tabl2.SotrudnikId from ls inner join tabl2 on tabl2.date=ls.Date

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал такую структуру:

[image: структура базы]

Отдельно вынесен справочник сотрудников (employees). И создана таблица (resp) указывающая, когда какой сотрудник обслуживал счет. В которой есть дата начала ведения счета сотрудником (sdt) и дата окончания (edt). Дата окончания у текущего сотрудника ставится либо в NULL, либо, как мне обычно больше нравится, в 01.01.3000. Единственная сложность в такой структуре - надо контролировать что бы по одному счету не было двух сотрудников с пересекающимися интервалами дат. Такой контроль желательно делать триггерами.

Получение сотрудников в данный момент ведущих счета сводится к:

```
select ls.ls_id, ls.Name, e.fio
  from ls
  join resp r on r.ls_id=ls.ls_id
  join employees e on e.emp_id=r.emp_id
 where now() between r.sdt and r.edt
```

Вместо now() можно поставить любую дату и получить кто вел счета на эту дату.

В принципе можно было бы в resp вести только дату, когда сотрудник взял счет на ведение. В этом случае не требовался бы контроль не пересечения интервалов дат. Но в таком случае выборка текущих сотрудников становится нетривиальной, ибо требует получить для каждого счета запись из resp с максимальной датой, меньшей текущей (искомой).